# Unable to assign authentication context with Conditional Access Policy on E5 Development Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

It worked few weeks ago, but when I tried same thing today I am getting error.
I am testing the authentication context with SHarepoint online for granular MFA requirement (this is preview feature)

1. In Azure Portal I created authentication context and CA policy with MFA that is using this context.
2. On SharePoint I ran this cmdlet

> Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/MFATest2
> -ConditionalAccessPolicy AuthenticationContext -AuthenticationContextName "MFAviaContext"

it worked in July, when I tried same thing today I got the error (my license is: Microsoft 365 E5 Developer (without Windows and Audio Conferencing)):

```
Set-SPOSite : You do not have required licenses to perform this operation. Please read here for licensing related requirements : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/authentication-context-example
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-SPOSite -Identity https://************.sharepoint.com/sites/MFATest ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSiteenter code here
```

Comment: I have reloaded the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell from last month (16.0.21411.12000) that I used (there was new version 10 days ago) but facing same problem.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT,
I am not sure if you have addressed the question! I am receiving identical error as mentioned by Marek-Sarad. Factually, I have the same license -"Microsoft 365 E5 Developer (without Windows and Audio Conferencing)" and I was able to use the same command back in July.

I use my developer tenant to tryout new things. This is where innovation happen and move it's way to corporate world.

What has changed in the backend that I can't run the command that worked perfectly a month ago?

Comment: Hello @Prodip, Its only supported in E5 and E5 Compliance License as per Microsoft Document. Can you please raise the same ask in [Microsoft Q & A Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html) for better visibility?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - I created an issue in Github where Set-SPOSite is documented at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8236. It's been couple of days and I haven't seen any update!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested it on my environment with the same command and it resulted in same error .

My license was Microsoft 365 E5 developer portal.

[image]

**From Microsoft Document :**

Using authentication context with SharePoint sites requires a Microsoft 365 E5 or Microsoft 365 E5 Compliance license for each user accessing a labeled site.

I tested again for different license i.e. Microsoft 365 E5 Compliance and it succeeded.

[image]

**Note:** Please use **Microsoft 365 E5 or Microsoft 365 E5 Compliance** license.

**Reference:**

[Manage site access based on sensitivity label - SharePoint in Microsoft 365 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/authentication-context-example)

Comment: Yes I set this dev tenant as new, so probably in July I had full E5 License. Strange it is omitted from the developer license.